# Haskell: How to pretty print number of seconds as a date and time?

Tags: date, haskell, timestamp, seconds

I have an integral value that is the number of seconds since the Epoch. I can output it as a big integer, but I want to show it as a human-readable date and time.

For example:

```
secToTimestamp :: Int32 -> [Char]
```

which returns something like:

```
2016-01-01 14:11:11
```

Comment: [`time`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time)

Answer (score 2):

In the interests of having a simple [`time`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) based solution (since `time` is the defacto module for manipulating anything time related):

```
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
import Data.Time.Format

secToTimestamp :: Int32 -> String
secToTimestamp = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%F %X" . posixSecondsToUTCTime . fromIntegral
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible use `unix-time` module

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Prelude
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8  as B
import           Data.UnixTime
import           Data.Int
import           Data.Functor

secToTimestampGMT :: Int32 -> [Char]
secToTimestampGMT t = B.unpack $ formatUnixTimeGMT "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S" $ UnixTime (fromIntegral t) 0

secToTimestamp :: Int32 -> IO [Char]
secToTimestamp t = B.unpack <$> (formatUnixTime "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S" $ UnixTime (fromIntegral t) 0)
```