# Converting a double to UTCTime

Tags: datetime, haskell

The title is all it is.

Assume I have a double:

```
let d = 11241241.10124012 :: Double
```

How do I get an instance of `UTCTime` corresponding to d, d as in unix seconds?

Comment: As in seconds since the epoch?

Comment: Yes. Seconds as in unix time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: How to pretty print number of seconds as a date and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541247/haskell-how-to-pretty-print-number-of-seconds-as-a-date-and-time)

Comment: Nitpicking: you mean "How do I get a value", rather than "How do I get an instance".

Comment: @duplode noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the double to a fractional in order for it to be understood as a `NominalDiffTime` value (which is an instance of `Fractional`).  Once it is understood as a `NominalDiffTime` value, then `posixSecondsToUTCTime` will handle the conversion (`POSIXTime` being a type synonym of `NominalDiffTime`).

```
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX(posixSecondsToUTCTime)

doubleToUTCTime d = posixSecondsToUTCTime $ realToFrac d
```

Comment: Nitpicking: "convert the double to a fractional" might be a somewhat confusing way of putting it to someone new to the language, as `Double` is a type while `Fractional` isn't, and also because `Double` is already a `Fractional`.